# Data is not being downloaded due to "too much work on main thread"

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, android-asynctask, android-volley

I'm facing trouble while downloading large data using API url. The problem is, the data loading activity is always running background and the threads do not work when the data set is large (it works fine for small data set). Moreover, while working on this activity of current version, the ***previous versions' APKs have been affected*** (which worked well previously).

The RUN button shows the DataLoadingActivity separately along with the main app.

[image: The RUN button shows the DataLoadingActivity separately along with the main app.]

The log is showing the following errors:

**1. Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.**

**2. A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.**

**3. Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.**

NOTE: The API URL shows JSON data properly if I run it on browser.

This segment calls the API and calls the methods of AsyncTask:

```
getRequest(DataLoadingActivity.this, "http://url_goes_here", new VolleyApiCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(int status, String apiContent) {
            if (status == AppConstants.SUCCESS_CODE) {

                try {

                    allData = new JSONObject(apiContent);
                    //checking category label and parsing in different threads so that parsing time gets minimized

                        if (allData.has("Education")) {
                            new SaveEducationDBTask(DataLoadingActivity.this).execute(allData.getJSONArray("Education"));
                        }

                        if (allData.has("Finance")) {
                            new SaveFinancialDBTask(DataLoadingActivity.this).execute(allData.getJSONArray("Finance"));

                        }

                        //  some more similar if-blocks

                    }

                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("_ward", wardClicked);
                    editor.putString("areakeyword", areaClicked);
                    editor.apply();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
        }

    });
```

SaveFinancialDBTask:

```
    public class SaveFinancialDBTask extends GenericSaveDBTask <JSONArray, Integer, Long, FinNewDBTable, FinancialNewDBModel> {


    public SaveFinancialDBTask(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx);
    }


    @Override
    public Long doInBackground(JSONArray... jsonArrays){
        return super.doInBackground(new FinNewDBTable(context), new FinancialNewDBModel(), jsonArrays);
    }
}
```

GenericSaveDBTask:

```
    public abstract class GenericSaveDBTask <Params, Progress, Result, TableType extends BaseDBTable, ModelType extends BaseModel> extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> {

    protected Context context;


    public GenericSaveDBTask(Context ctx){
        this.context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {

        Log.e(" Data collection : ",  "done " + getClass());
        if (((Long) result).longValue() == 0.0 && countofDb < NUMBER_OF_TASKS) { // Means the task is successful
            countofDb++;

            SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putInt("KValue", countofDb);
            editor.apply();

        }
    }


    protected Long doInBackground(TableType table, ModelType model, JSONArray... jsonArrays) {


        Log.e(" Data collection : ",  "ongoing " + getClass());

        JSONArray data = jsonArrays[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            try {
                if (!data.isNull(i)) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = data.getJSONObject(i);
                    table.insertItem(model.parse(jsonObject));
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return new Long(-1);
            }
        }
        return new Long(0);
    }

    @Override

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        Log.e(" Data collection : ",  "starting " + getClass());
    }


}
```

Interface VolleyApiCallback:

```
    public interface VolleyApiCallback {
    void onResponse(int status, String apiContent);
}
```

getRequest method in VolleyApiParser:

error.networkResponse.statusCode shows error:

> **Attempt to read from field 'int com.android.volley.NetworkResponse.statusCode' on a null object
>   reference**

```
public static void getRequest(final Context ctx, final String apiUrl,
                              final VolleyApiCallback vApiCb) {
    getRequest(ctx, apiUrl, vApiCb, Request.Priority.NORMAL);
}

public static void getRequest(final Context ctx, final String apiUrl,
                              final VolleyApiCallback vApiCb,
                              final Request.Priority priority) {
    if (!AppUtils.isNetConnected(ctx)) {

        ToastMessageDisplay.setText(ctx,ctx.getString(R.string.connect_internet));
        ToastMessageDisplay.showText(ctx);

    return;
}


    Character c=apiUrl.charAt(0);
    Character c1= apiUrl.charAt(1);

     if(c.equals('h')&&(c1.equals('t')))
     {
         FinalUrl=apiUrl;
     }
    else
         FinalUrl= AppConstants.API_URL + apiUrl ;


    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            FinalUrl,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Lg.i(TAG, VOLLEY_TAG + " : Response got: " + response);
                    vApiCb.onResponse(AppConstants.SUCCESS_CODE, response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    try {
                        if (error != null)
                            Lg.e(TAG, VOLLEY_TAG + " : Error : toString=" + error.toString()
                                    + ", net response code=" + error.networkResponse.statusCode
                                    + ", NetResponse data length = " + error.networkResponse.data.length);
                        else
                            Lg.e(TAG,
                                    "onErrorResponse :  VolleyError is also null (>_<)");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    vApiCb.onResponse(AppConstants.ERR_VOLLEY_CODE,
                            "API Response error! Check connection & tried URL ...");
                }
            }) {

        @Override
        public Priority getPriority() {
            return priority;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getTag() {
            return VOLLEY_TAG;
        }
    };
    VolleySingleton.getInstance(ctx).addToRequestQueue(strReq);
}
```

[Error log on attempting to fetch data from URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5gX7.png)

Can anyone kindly suggest what should be done now to stop the background activity? I'm new in Android app development.

Comment: A [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) may be what you need to keep your stuff running.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @JimmyB. I'm looking into it. :)

Comment: Indeed, move heavy operations to the background then update UI accordingly when done